# Error when compiling using arduino-builder on mac os x

Tags: macos, arduino

Arduino version: 1.8.2

Max OS X version: 10.12.3

`arduino-builder -compile -hardware /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools -fqbn arduino:avr:uno -verbose SimpleTimer.ino`

Error:
`fork/exec /bin/avr-g++: no such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

I had to put in a couple fixes before the above command worked.

- In file
  `/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/platform.txt`
  change this property: 
  `compiler.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/`
- In file `/Applications/Arduino.app//Contents/Java/hardware/platform.txt` 
  change this property:
  `tools.ctags.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder/ctags/5.8-arduino11`

Credit:
https://github.com/Sloeber/arduino-eclipse-plugin/issues/236

Answer (score 1):

Marcello's answer worked for me, but I would propose a more convenient solution in the form of a wrapper-script to do all the dirty work:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
arduino-builder \
  -compile \
  -hardware /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware \
  -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools \
  -fqbn arduino:avr:uno \
  -libraries ../libraries/ \
  -prefs=compiler.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/ \
  -prefs=tools.ctags.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder/ctags/5.8-arduino11 \
  -verbose \
  SimpleTimer.ino
```